# Why is PostgreSQL's auto-explain not working in AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, postgresql-9.6, logging

These are my settings:

[image: settings list]

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/auto-explain.html), as far as I can tell, this combination of settings along with a `statement_timeout` value of 3600000 *should* mean that hour-long queries time out, and well before then, they and anything else longer than ~214ms should be producing EXPLAIN output in the logs.  But they're not.

1. `shared_preload_libraries` already contained `auto_explain` by default when I checked.
2. The parameters above are applied to the server.
3. I've restarted the instance after applying the parameters.
4. My back end has reported an incidence of `canceling statement due to statement timeout` (which only started happening after I set `statement_timeout`) but there is nothing in the logs (at all, let alone in the vicinity of the time reported) showing anything other than xlog starting and stopping.

What else could be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto_explain` only logs a statement upon successful completion. If it gets cancelled, it does not get logged by auto_explain.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but very helpful to know!  Thanks!